# How to increase RWIN Value in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, internet, bandwidth, tcp, internet-speed

We all know that a lot of things have been deprecated and there was also the introduction of auto scaling in earlier windows versions.

Right now after using this analyzer http://www.speedguide.net/analyzer.php

My Default TCP Recieve windows (RWIN) = 262144 in Microsoft Edge Browser only.

I have a 25Mbps connection.

For downloading I am able to utilize my most bandwidth. But somehow my windows applications such as browsers and other softwares arent able to utilize it.

My speednet test say that my bandwidth is 2Mbps which isnt right at all, as I am able to download file with the speed of nearly 2.8-3.2MBps which is about 25Mbps in bandwidth.

I searched and searched but didnt find any solution to my problem. I tried changing " netsh int tcp set global autotuninglevel=experimental" but it just increased the utilization and rwin value by little.

By keeping netsh int tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled

And Enabling CTCP in Windows 10 using a tweak, my browsing experience is really great but still its not like how it was used to be in earlier versions of Windows 7 where i was able to change/increase RWIN value. My uploads speeds have been limited too.

when using that analyzer in Google chrome it says that RWIN Value is just 65536. Which according to me is the main reason I am not getting a proper browsing experience as per bandwidth. Speedtest just show 1mbps up and 1mpbps down.

There's a reference that how windows is killing internet these days. http://duckware.com/blog/how-windows-is-killing-internet-download-speeds/index.html

Which told The issue only happens on fast Internet connections.

About RWIN For example, with a 65,535 byte receive window you can only achieve an approximate throughput of 5.24 megabits per second (Mbps) on a path with a 100ms RTT, regardless of the transmission path's actual bandwidth. With today's high-BDP transmission paths, the originally designed TCP window size, even at its maximum value, becomes a throughput bottleneck.

In Windows 10 you cant set congestionprovider as ctcp globally. Its not supported.

Rather you can set it as supplemental congestionprovider.

Which could increase you connection experience a little better.

So if any one could help me out with it Please do.

Answer (score 1):

You wote that:

> "In Windows 10 you cant set congestionprovider as ctcp globally. Its not supported".

This is incorrect. Rather, the `netsh` command-line utility is broken on Windows 10.

It incorrectly reports that congestion provider is None, when in fact it is usually `CTCP` or `DCTCP` by default on Windows 10.

To verify this, run PowerShell (Start->PowerShell) and then run:

```
Get-NetTCPSetting
```

Explore around there, I think you'll find you can adjust some settings to your liking with `Set-NetTCPSetting`.

Comment: Please format your answer so that it is more understandable.

Comment: Already know that, but have your tried, changing them ? According to my find, it doesn't work. Did it work for you ? Right now using the latest Win 10 build.